# Getting Unhandled exception error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: c#, selenium

i'm getting an error when trying to use Selenium w/ c#. I did use selenium yesterday and I had 0 problems. And was wondering what could cause this.

The error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

What I do to recreate the error

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
        driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com")

    }
```

Comment: From the details of your error, it looks like someone removed the WebDriver DLL from wherever your program is looking for it.

Comment: I use jetbrain's IDA (Rider), and it lets me install packages from the IDA. And I have reinstalled it and I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webdriver.dll is missing.

The first thing I suggest you to check is the binaries output folder (for example bin/debug folder, which you can check from your visual studio project settings). You will find all your referenced dlls and your project itself in this folder. It is likely that your Webdriver.dll is not being copied to the output folder. This usually happens when you add an external reference (dll) by using the "Add Reference" visual studio dialog box. To fix the issue, click on the Webdriver dll reference, and in the properties window, make sure to set `copylocal = true`.

Comment: I use jetbrains IDE (Rider)... And Webdriver.dll is in my references tab. Also I can run it in my IDE w/o any problem, it's just when i build it.

Comment: @nooby Adding a dll to your reference tab makes your compiler happy but it does not necessarily mean the dll is being copied to the output directory. You need to make sure your IDE is doing the copy. CLR has a complicated mechanics to locate the dll during the runtime (Here is a document but you do not have to read through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx). If the dll is expected to exist in the target environment's GAC, the IDE will not copy the (Webdriver) dll to the output folder.